# How to add button near separator in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using UITableView with static cells to build interface as shown below, but i don't know how to put button near separator between two cells. Can I do it by writing custom separator? What is the best way to do this?

https://prnt.sc/oyuul3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No writing a custom separator doesn't seem to be the solution here. What I would recommend is reducing the width of the TableViewCells, and adding a button as a subview of the TableView

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Use UIScrollView instead of UITableView.
2. Use Section HeaderView of FooterView to simulate the separator.
3. Add a button in UITableView like watermark. Implement UIScorllDelegate for UITableView, calculate the offset you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's not 2 or 3 cells, It's **ONLY ONE cell** composed with many UILabels, 2 UITextFields, a separator line image, and a UIButton.

For UITableView, refer following image to `None` seprator. It will remove native separator line of `UITableView`.

As for me, I will use `No Selection` for designing a form with `static cells` content.

[image]